# "_set" in a queryset object in Django

Tags: python, django, object, django-models, django-queryset

I'm a bit confused how to use `_set` in a `QuerySet` in Django. For example, an object Blog `b`, and the object `Entry` related by the attribute `entry_set`. What is the meaning of `b.entry_set.all()`?

I would appreciate if someone could use this example to display the possible output.

Answer (score 72):

What you are seeing is a [reverse related object lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

In your example:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    pass

class Entry(..):
    blog = Blog(..)
```

Now, given object `e` of type `Entry`, you would do `e.blog` to access the related object `Blog` - which is a forward relation.
The `_set` is a reverse lookup class variable django puts in for you.

So, given object `b` - you would do:

```
entries = b.entry_set.all()
```

The reason the reverse is a queryset is, ForeignKey is `1-to-many` relationship. Hence, the reverse is a queryset.

The `_set` object is made available when [`related_name` is not specified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

Comment: Could we not just say entries = b.entry.all() and what happens if we do. Just trying to understand what 'set' does ?

Comment: Did you read up the explanation ? Also did you go through the link ?

Comment: had to read it a few times. I guess the word '_set' is not actually setting anything, rather "get"ing all the related objects. That is how I understand it.

Comment: Think of set in queryset instead of getters and setters

Answer (score 45):

**Briefly speaking:**

Suppose you have a model `Car` and a model `Wheel`. `Wheel` has a foreign key relationship with `Car` as follows:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    pass

class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # on_delete parameter is mandatory in Django 2.0
```

Let's say `w` is an instance of `Wheel`, and `c` is an instance of `Car`:

```
>>> w.car # returns the related Car object to w
>>> c.wheel_set.all() # returns all Wheel objects related to c
```

**Detailed explanation**

Using the models defined above, a `Wheel` object `w` can get its associated `Car` object by accessing the `car` attribute: `w.car`.

If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of that model will have access to the related *foreign* object via a simple attribute of the model.

According to the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship.

In this case, a `Car` object `c` has access to a list of all related `Wheel` objects via the `wheel_set` attribute: `c.wheel_set.all()`.

If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a `Manager` that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this `Manager` is named `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name, lowercased. This `Manager` returns `QuerySets`, which can be filtered and manipulated.

Comment: Any clue why why it is `wheel_set` and not `Wheel_set`? Why is this not case sensitive?

Comment: @DevanshSharma, it is because this is the default behavior when you do not specify `related_name` in the field declaration. It uses the `<model_name>_set` as default value for `related_name`  ([see more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#default-related-name)). [Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ad811335bdd57d65dddbc05375ec3a70b59c96fb/django/db/models/options.py#L155) you can see that the name of class is lowercased, so that is why it is not `Wheel_set`.

Answer (score 1):

[_set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) can access the child model which has the foreign key of the parent model.

For example, there is **the child model `Product`** which has the foreign key of **the parent model `Category`** as shown below:

```py
"models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

Then, you can access **the child model `Product`** from **the parent model `Category`** with `_set` as shown below:

```py
category_obj = Category.objects.all()[0]
product_obj = category_obj.product_set.all()[0]
                                # ↑ Here
print(product_obj.id, product_obj.name, product_obj.price)
```

Output:

```
1 Apple 10.00
```

But, you cannot access **the parent model `Category`** from **the child model `Product`** with `_set` as shown below:

```py
product_obj = Product.objects.all()[0]
category_obj = product_obj.category_set.all()[0]
                                 # ↑ Cannot access "Category" with "_set"
print(category_obj.id, category_obj.name)
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'category_set'

But, you can access **the parent model `Category`** with **the foreign key field `category`** in **the child model `Product`** as shown below:

```py
product_obj = Product.objects.all()[0]
category_obj = product_obj.category
                           # ↑ Here
print(category_obj.id, category_obj.name)
```

Output:

```
1 Fruits
```