# Django: How correctly show list of objects in related models?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

I have 2 models: Product and Section.

**models.py:**

```
class Section(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,)

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,)
  section = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to show list of sections with their products in template. I used  `regroup` tag for this task but have some problems.

1) Sections without any product won't be visible. How to show sections without products too?

2) In database some products have NULL value in section field. How to group these products into one section?

I will be grateful for any advice or example! =)

**views.py:**

```
context['products'] = Product.objects.select_related('section').order_by('section')
```

**template:**

```
{% regroup products by section as products_by_section %}

{% for section in products_by_section %}
    {{ section.grouper}}
    {% for product in section.list %}
        {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: > 1) Sections without any product don't visible. How to show sections without products too?


If there is no Product instance that is linked to a Section, they're ```not related```, are they? How do you want to select "related unrelated objects"?

Comment: @py_dude Hello! You are absolutely right! I think I need reorganize my code. My main aim to show all sections and products related with these sections. If section without products show message like: no products. I hope you understand me. Do you have any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a default section and add it to all the `products` having null section value. Then you can query on `Section` model to get all the sections and their related products. This will simplify the design, and remove all the null checks from the code.

Query will be of the format:

> sections = Section.objects.all().prefetch_related('product_set')

Now you have `sections` along with their products already grouped. You can create a dictionary with key as `section_id` and value as list of products

```
section_products_dict = {}
for section in sections:
    section_products_dict[section.id] = section.product_set.all()
```

And then you can pass this dictionary to template. Once you have `sections` list, you can query products in many different ways. I have created dictionary, but you can use it as per your need (like using directly in template).

If adding a default section is not possible, then do two separate queries for product and sections and combine them with `section_id` as key and value as list or `products`.

Comment: Thank you to your advice. I am trying to use your solution and it looks nice but I have little problem. Let me try to explain. I sort section like this: `Section.objects.all().prefetch_related('prodcut_set').order_by('order_by')`. It return me section with next ids: `3,1, 6, 5`. Which is correct. But in `section_products_dict` I have `{1: Queryset, 3: Queryset, 5: Queryset, 6: Queryset,}` Why dict sorted?

Comment: Dictionaries does not maintain order. Use `OrderedDict` if you want to maintain order. Or you can pass list and dict both. List is maintaining the order and dict is for data lookup.

Comment: Thats the problem. If dict is not maintain order why in my case it ordered? How to fix it?

Comment: I notice that when we use `section_products_dict[section.id]` dict is sorted cause `section.id` is `int`. When I changed it to `section_products_dict[str(section.id)]` it changed but items are not in the order in which they were added. Do you any ideas about that?

Comment: Thank you, bro! `OrderDict` help me! =)

Answer (score 1):

Send `sections` that has products in context data instead of `products`

```
context['sections'] = Section.objects.exclude(product_set__isnull=True)
```

and in template loop on `sections`

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {{ section.name }}
    {% for product in section.product_set.all %}
        {{ product.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

> Read more for making django query on [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Comment: Can you explain what `product_set` mean here, please? `Section` model don't have product field, so I am little confused.

Comment: product_set is a reverse lookup, you have mentioned section foreign key in product table.

Comment: have a look at this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080970/3404994 to get a better understanding of `_set`

Comment: Well in fact `Section` model has name as `FinSection` in my case. So I tried to write like `finsection_set` but it didn't work. Raise error. Is it mean that I need to set `related_name` attribute in `ForeignKey` (section field of Section model)?

Comment: whats your Product model name, use `_set` after it

Comment: My `Product` model has name `FinProduct`. I tried to set `finproduct_set` but it also raise error.

Comment: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'fincode_set' into field.

Comment: the error is not related to what we are doing, How can it raise error `fincode_set` field, if you are using `finproduct_set `

Comment: Sorry it mistake. I mean `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'finproduct_set' into field.`

Comment: have you used `related_name` in model while declaring  `section = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)` forgein key

Comment: Right now there is no `related_name` in `section` field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165717/discussion-between-satendra-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).