# Django ForeignKey

Tags: django, relationship

I'm struggling to do a reverse search via the shell for a foreign key

models.py:

```
class Investor(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

 def __str__ (self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Investment(models.Model):
 investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 feeder = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
 amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default="1")

 def __str__ (self):
    return self.investor

class Fund(models.Model):
 feeder = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__ (self):
    return  self.feeder
```

If I enter the shell:

```
a = Investment.objects.get(pk=1)
a.investor.first_name -> this works
```

On the other hand :

```
b = Investor.objects.get(pk=1)
b.investment doesn't work... 
b.investor doesn't work
b.investment.feeder neither..
```

Always got the error 'Investor has not attributed '....' -> 
How can i search through the reverse relationships? Thanks !!

Comment: What you actually want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_set in Django for a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080864/set-in-django-for-a-queryset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key is a one-to-many relationship, not one-to-one. Here an Investment has one Investor, but an Investor has many Investments. So from your Investor you need to use the reverse relation, which be default ends in `set`, and is a Manager:

```
b.investment_set.all()
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Many thanks ! Indeed. Any idea how I can use this in a html template. I'm facing there the same problem: investment.investor.first_name works. But, investor.investment.feeder doesn't... Thanks !

Comment: But why would you think that would work? I've told you, you need to use investment_set, and it's a manager that returns a queryset which you need to iterate through because there are *many* Investments.

Comment: Thing is that I've got a filter set. And when I include a for-loop to iterate over the investment_set, the investors without any investment disappear from the Queryset... Maybe I should create a separate topic for this one

Comment: Yes that sounds best