# Django Models - how to pull data from 2 models and render

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a survey-like app using Django. I have 3 models (Survey, Question, Answer). I need to query the Questions model and pull back the Questions PLUS the possible Answers for each question. 
Then, i need to display it on the html page as a single question, with the possible answers in a list or other element.

Django==2.2.1 / Pillow==6.1.0/ pytz==2019.1/ sqlparse==0.3.0/ Python 3.7
I tried going from the Answers model but I end up with duplicate data and uncertain how to render.

MODELS.PY

```
class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_sequence = models.IntegerField()
    question_to_ask = models.CharField(max_length=4000, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_to_ask

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    possibleAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    possibleAnswer_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.possibleAnswer
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def survey(request):    
    q = [x for x in Question.objects.all().values()]
    questions_dict = {'questions': q}

    # a = [x for x in Answer.objects.select_related().all()] 
    # answers_dict = {'answers': a}

    return render(request, 'survey_app/survey.html', context=questions_dict)
```

.HTML

```
<body>
      <div class=questions>
        {% if questions %}

      <h1> {% for q in questions %}</h1>
        <p> {{ q.question_to_ask }}</p>

          <p> {% for a in answers %}</p>
          <p> {{ a.question.question_to_ask }}</p> 
            {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
          <p> NO RECORDS SHOWN</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
</body>
```

My goals is to have this display on html:

Question_To_Ask (q1)

- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q1)
- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q1)

Question_To_Ask (q2)

- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q2)
- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q2)
- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q2)
- PossibleAnswer / possibleAnswer_image  (for q2)

etc...

Comment: For your reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080864/set-in-django-for-a-queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
your_question_object.answer = your_question_object.answer_set.all()
```

This should add all the possible answers of your question which are having the foreign key as your question to `answer` attribute for `your_question_object`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with {% endfor %}

```
<body>
  <div class=questions>
    {% if questions %}

  <h1> {% for q in questions %}</h1>
    <p> {{ q.question_to_ask }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      <p> {% for a in answers %}</p>
      <p> {{ a.question.question_to_ask }}</p> 
        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
      <p> NO RECORDS SHOWN</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```