# Only friends posts are not showing

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogPost Webapp, AND i am stuck on an Error.

models.py

`Post Model`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
```

views.py

```
def friends_posts(request,user_id):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(post_owner=user_id)
    profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,user_id=user_id)
    p = request.user.profile
    you = p.user
    friends = p.friends.all()

    context = {'posts':posts,'profiles':profiles,'friends':friends}
    return render(request, 'friends_posts.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
path('friends_posts/<int:user_id>/',views.friends_posts,name='friends_posts'),
```

friends_posts.html

```
      {% for user_p in friends %}

      {{ user_p.posts.all }}

      {% endfor %}
```

**The Problem**

friends_posts page is not showing Friends posts.

It is showing all the information of friends but NOT showing the posts of friends.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to show `all the posts of friends of request.user`.

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: just print **{{ user_p }}** you will get friends data

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: @Progam show your model then

Comment: @Charnel, I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for user_p in friends %}

    {% for post in user_p.user.post_set.all %}
        <p>Title: {{post.post_title}}
        <br />
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Progam Updated. Have a look.

Comment: @Progam have a look at inner forloop again. I just updated.

Comment: @Progam To learn about reverse lookup(`_set`) have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080970/10860596

Answer (score 1):

According to your models `p.friends.all()` return `Profile` model queryset. When you are trying to display `user_p.friends.posts.all` all posts from all user friends this fails because of `friends` is M2M field on `Profile` model and it doesn't have attribute called `posts`. If you really need all posts from all friends to be displayed, then you should iterate over `frieds` first:

```
{% for friend in user_p.friends.all %}
    {% for post in fried.user.post_set.all %}
        {{ post }}
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You.  but it is showing nothing. When i input `{{ user_p.friends.all }}` then it shows my all friends. BUT when i input `{{ user_p.friends.posts.all }}` it shows nothing.

Comment: what if i change `post_owner Foreignkey Profile instead of User ?

Comment: Pls check my answer again - I didn't noticed that `posts` is not a `related_name` on `Friend` neither `User` models.

Comment: I really appreciate your Help. IT WORKED. @Biplove gave the right suggestion