# Django related_name with _set function

Tags: python, django, forms, set

I'm using related_name tag in my models and I'm trying to filter my form with _set function. However I'm having this error;

```
  AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'contact_owner_set'
```

I think the problem is in right here;

```
self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_owner_set.order_by('name')
```

I've tried to remove related_name field and change this bit to;

```
self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_owner_set.order_by('name')
```

However I need related_name for my other functions. Is there any way to figure this out?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("client-detailview", kwargs={"slug": self.slug}) 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Contact(models.Model):
    client_owner = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contact_client') # client.contact_client
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("contact-detailview", kwargs={"slug": self.slug}) 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client_owner) + " - " + str(self.name)

class Action(models.Model):
    client_owner = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='action_client') # client.action_client
    contact_owner = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='action_contact', blank=True, null=True) # contact.action_contact
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.topic) + " - " + str(self.user_owner) + " - " + str(self.client_owner) + " - " + str(list(self.contact_owner.all().values_list('name', flat=True)))
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Action, Contact
from .forms import ActionForm

class ActionListView(ListView):
    model = Action
    context_object_name = 'actions'
    template_name = 'crm/action_list.html'

class ActionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Action
    form_class = ActionForm
    template_name = 'crm/action_form.html' 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('action_changelist')

class ActionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Action
    form_class = ActionForm
    template_name = 'crm/action_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('action_changelist')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Action, Contact

class ActionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Action 
        fields = ('client_owner', 'contact_owner', 'topic') 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = Contact.objects.none()

        if 'client_owner' in self.data:
            try:
                alan1 = int(self.data.get('client_owner'))
                self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = Contact.objects.filter(client_owner_id = alan1)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk and self.instance.client_owner: 
            print(self.instance.client_owner)
            print(type(self.instance.contact_owner))
            print(self.instance.contact_owner.values())
            self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_owner_set.order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) defines the name of reverse relation, so in your case, there is no model with relation `contact_owner_set`.

For example, if you want to access client contacts, you should use the `client.contact_client` attribute; if you want to get the contact's actions, you have to use the `contact.action_contact` attribute.

But there is no relation `contact_owner_set` in particular here:

```
self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_owner_set.order_by('name')
```

`self.instance.client_owner` is `Client` instance and `Client` instance has no attribute `contact_owner_set`.

And you definitely have to rename your `related_name` by using plural for more code readability.

Comment: I see your point and I'm quite aware of it. However I'm stuck with related_name field and I have to use it for other reasons. So, if is there any other way to filter my updateview with _set method.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what does "filter with _set method" means. When you don't specify `related_name` Django uses the default relation name. For example, if you don't specify related_name in `Contact.client_owner`, then you can access contacts by reverse relation `Client.contact_set`. And if you specify `related_name='contact_client'` then you have `Client.contact_client` instead of `Client.contact_set`.

Comment: So there is no any "_set method" filtration in Django, it's all about accessing object by reverse relation.

Comment: You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080970/17556172) for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, to sum up this "self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_client.order_by('name')" solved my problem.

Comment: My pleasure, sir! And if my answer to the original question was helpful, feel free to mark it as right.

Comment: Yeah, I marked your answer as right !