# For loop inside a IF condition to show right category on django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to show the correct articles in the category section using an if condition with a for loop inside, so far I'm displaying all the articles and not the only ones that supposed to be in the category.

**home.html screeenshot**

[image]

**home.html**

```html
{% if articles.category == Sports %}
    {% for article in articles %}
    <div class="position-relative">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="{{article.cover.url}}" style="object-fit: cover;">
        <div class="overlay position-relative bg-light">
            <div class="mb-2" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <a href="">{{article.title}}</a>
                <span class="px-1">/</span>
                <span>{{article.created_at}}</span>
            </div>
            <a class="h4 m-0" href="">{{article.description}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```py
def home (request):   
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    articles = Article.objects.filter( is_published=True).order_by('-category')
    
    return render (request,'pages/home.html',
    context={
    'cats': cats, 
    'articles': articles
    })
```

Comment: `articles` is a **queryset** it doesn't have an attribute `category` so `articles.category` evaluates to an empty string, given that you don't have a `Sports` variable in your context either that also evaluates to an empty string. The view should pass the appropriate data to the template (The template shouldn't need to do the filtering), the answer below shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding it like that, you could let the users search for categories with something like this:

```py
articles = Article.objects.filter(category__icontains=q).values('title')
```

where `q` would be the user input in the form.

Comment: yeah thats a good idea, but i want to show like this (i will upload the img on the post)

Comment: then I think you're just missing the quotation marks around "Sports", unless you have two separate models for Articles and Categories then you need to connect them with a foreign key and use `__set` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080864/set-in-django-for-a-queryset

Comment: hmmm its still not working, it is showing all the articles and not only the 'Sports' only